# Protractor time-out while trying to download file

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I've written a simple script in Protractor that selects some option from the screen, and on hitting submit, a file should download i.e html content is exported as PDF. All seems fine, except that Protractor times out giving the error - "Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL".

Below is the code :-

```
    describe('Generate Reports', function () {
        it('should enable the user to generate reports', function (done) {
            element.all(by.tagName('button')).get(0).click();
            browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            var links = element.all(by.css('.dropdown')).get(0);
            links.click();
            links.all(by.tagName('li')).get(0).click(); // first OP

            browser.driver.sleep(5000);
            browser.waitForAngular();

            element.all(by.css('.btn-primary')).get(1).click();
            browser.driver.sleep(5000);
            //For report download
            var links = element(by.model('ReportType'));
            links.click();
            browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'Summary Report')).click();
            browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            element(by.model('ReportDownload')).click();
            browser.driver.sleep(3000);
            element.all(by.id('btnDownload')).click();
            browser.driver.sleep(30000);
            browser.waitForAngular();
});
});
```

I've even tried increasing the Jasmine Default Time-out Interval to 60 seconds or so, in the config file. Usually during normal execution, the file downloads within 3-4 seconds. 
But here, although I've set a time duration of nearly 30 secs I'm still getting the error. Please help!! What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `var links = element(by.model('ReportType')).click();
            links.click();` links var is itself clicked again why are you clicking it?

Comment: @Danny - I apologize for the error :( I've edited the code copy and re-updated. Any ideas on what could be causing the timeout ?

Comment: **this is not the solution**......check what is happening in browser when protractor is executed. Find at which point it takes delay, like clicking the dropdown maynot be executed or other click would have been not executed. Check and update the question, as in where it is taking so long.